# Sails 1.0 - sails-disk for dev/test and sails-mongo for production

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

In Sails 1.0, I'm trying to use `sails-mongo` for dev and production and `sails-disk` for test. Before version 1.0 I could do this, but now I receive an error:

```
error: Error: In model 'user', primary key 'id' must have either
 'required' or 'autoIncrement' set.
```

My code:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true },
    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' }, //<---- error Here!

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    ......
}
```

Can I do some workaround to make it work?

Comment: It's a known issue: https://trello.com/c/hs7cWuaC/100-sails-disk-mongo-mode-some-way-of-using-string-ids

Answer (score 0):

Add a `required` rule on your `id` field.

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true },
    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id', required: true }, //<---- Add it here

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    ......
}
```

Comment: I already tested it. Receive an error: `error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Consistency violation: Attempting to tear down a datastore (`default`) which is not currently registered with this adapter.  This is usually due to a race condition in userland code (e.g. attempting to tear down the same ORM instance more than once), or it could be due to a bug in this adapter.  (If you get stumped, reach out at http://sailsjs.com/support.)`

Comment: The error can be ignored regarding to the developer response in this issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4069

Comment: He is using sails-mongo (`adapter: 'sails-mongo',`), i'm using sails-disk. It's not the same issue.